# How can I achieve a stackframe from not getting destroyed after returning from the function?

Tags: c

I am trying to store elements for Fibonacci series in the array which is inside the function and after returning from function by "return arr " my stack frame is getting destroyed and I am unable to receive values in main function. I wanted to use recursion only and printing from main function these are my conditions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *fib(int *num, int *first, int *second, int i, int *arr);

int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("Enter any number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &num);
  int first = 0, second = 1, i = 0;
  int arr[num];
  int *result = fib(&num, &first, &second, i, arr);
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    printf("%d ", result[i]);
}

int *fib(int *num, int *first, int *second, int i, int *arr)
{
  int temp;
  if (*first == 0)
    printf("%d ", *first);
  if (*num < 0)
  {
    if (*second == 1)
      printf("%d ", *second);
    temp = *first - *second;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
    if (*second > *num && *second < -*num)
    {
      *(arr + i) = *second;
      return fib(num, first, second, i++, arr);
    }
    else
      return arr;
  }
  else
  {
    temp = *first + *second;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;

    if (*second >= *num + 3)
      return arr;
    else
    {
      *(arr + i) = *second;
      return fib(num, first, second, i++, arr);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation/whitespace. This code is needlessly difficult to read.

Comment: I've written a token answer to this exact question, but you're really asking the wrong question. Instead of focusing on trying to break how computers work, focus on explaining what the actual problem is - expand on _"I am unable to receive values in main function"_ in a way that we can actually help you solve it (ideally with a [MCVE]). Since all your real data is stored in `main`, I have no idea how stack frame destruction comes into this.

Comment: This code is incredibly convoluted for such a simple task. I'd throw this code away and start over from scratch rethinking everything. The whole program should be no longer than 15 lines.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My query is i am storing values in function and i am returning address to the main function and i am getting no errors but i am getting segmentation fault in run time.

Comment: @ARUNKUMAR You are going to need to provide some detail and evidence. The address you return is that of a thing that exists _in_ `main` and therefore already exists. Did you write out of bounds and corrupt memory? You need to methodically debug this.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with a corrupted stack.  You just have a bug.  You should try stepping through your code with a debugger and / or add lots of `printf` calls to find out where.

Comment: Why do you need to return an int * and assign it to a new pointer if you will always be returning the address of arr from that function. Wouldn't it be better to make fib a void function and just change the values of arr using the pointer given?

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

You are trying to fight against the very definition of what a stack frame is, and you are losing.

And you will always lose!

Instead, properly structure your program to pass data around in the way you need, in accordance with the rules and specifications of the language.

Comment: In spite of the phrasing in the question, the array being returned `arr`, is not defined inside the function `fib`. It is defined in `main` and passed to `fib` via pointer. Whatever problem this code has, it is not one of attempting to return a pointer to an object local to the function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Correct. See my comments under the question. I have answered the question posed, but the question is indeed "wrong" and the OP will have to ask a new one to address their actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely achieve what you're wanting do without protecting the information on the function stackframes, as I don't believe your error has anything to do with that. With that said, recursion with Fibonacci numbers is kind of pointless compared to the iterative approach, it just ends up spamming extra stackframes when none are needed.

I took inspiration from Jabberwocky's answer and made an example with "recursion", though it ends up just being a fancy for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fib(int num, int *arr, int pos);

int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("Enter any number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  int arr[num];
  if (num > 1) {
    arr[0] = 0 ;
    arr[1] = 1 ;
  }
  int pos = 2;
  fib(num, arr, pos);

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}

void fib(int num, int *arr, int pos)
{
  if (pos < num && pos > 1)
  {
    arr[pos] = arr[pos - 2] + arr[pos - 1];
    fib(num, arr, pos + 1);
  }  
  else {
      return;
  }
}
```

This stores all values into arr which is allocated in main, so deletion of stackframes has no effect. The fib function even when recursive does not need to return anything because it has the array pointer and can directly change the values of the array. Of course more error checking is needed but I think this is sufficient to get the idea across.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat off topic, but you probably simply want this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fib(int num, int *arr);

int main()
{
  int num;
  printf("Enter any number : \n");
  scanf("%d", &num);

  int arr[num] = { 0, 1 } ;
  fib(num, arr);

  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}

void fib(int num, int *arr)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  {
    arr[i + 2] = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
  }  
}
```

Using recursion is pretty pointless here.
This is untested code, there may be bugs.

Comment: I have no issues with logic I know logic for Fibonacci but my condition is i wanted to use recursion and wanted finally the output to be printed from main function

Comment: @ARUNKUMAR well then you need to debug your totally bloated pointless code.

Comment: arr[ i + 2 ] in your fib function will continue to assign values past the bounds of the array since it goes all the way to num. I think it should be arr[i] = arr[ i - 2] + arr[i - 1] with i initialized to 2.

Comment: I made an answer that builds off of your example to show how it's done recursively if you don't mind, although there is still no reason not to use iteration in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>       



 int fib ( int *num , int *first , int *second , int count , int *arr ) ;      


 int main() 

 {

 char ch;

 do

 {
    int num = 0;

    printf("Enter any number : \n");

    scanf("%d", &num);

    int first = 0, second = 1, count = 0,size = num;           

if(num < 0)
    {
        size = -(num);                                 
    }
    int arr[size];                                          
    count = fib(&num, &first, &second, count, arr);        
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(arr + j));                      
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Do you want to repeat ? Y / N\n");              
    scanf("\n\n%c", &ch);
  } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');                             
}                                                                 

int fib(int *num, int *first, int *second, int count, int *arr)   
{

 int temp;
 if (*first == 0)
 {
    printf("%d ", *first);                                  
 }
 if (*num < 0)                                               
 {
    if (*second == 1)                                       
    {
        printf("%d ", *second);
    }
    temp = *first - *second;                                
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
    if (*second >= *num && *second <= -*num)
    {
        *(arr + count) = *second;                      
        return fib(num, first, second, count+1, arr);  
    }
 }
  else if(*num > 0)                                        
 {
    temp = *first + *second;
    *first = *second;                                    
    *second = temp;
    if (*second == 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", *second);                        
    }
    if (*second <= *num)
    {
        *(arr + count) = *second;                      
        return fib(num, first, second, count+1, arr);  
    }
  }
  return count;                                           
 }
```

Comment: i am using recursion and also printing from main function . thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int *fib(int *num, int *first, int *second, int i, int *arr)
{
  int temp;
  if (*first == 0)
    printf("%d ", *first);
  if (*num < 0)
  {
    if (*second == 1)
      printf("%d ", *second);
    temp = *first - *second;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
    if (*second > *num && *second < -*num)
    {
      *(arr + i) = *second;
      return fib(num, first, second, i++, arr);
    }
    else
      return arr;
  }
  else
  {
    temp = *first + *second;
    *first = *second;
    *second = temp;
```

Comment: In addition to ensuring this compiles, it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially valuable for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions. Would you mind updating your comment with additional details?